# Yet another 2018 puzzle

Tags: discussion

As of late, there have been numerous puzzles regarding "making x to y using the numbers 2, 0, 1 and 8". So many, in fact, that imho it's just plain annoying. Just a few examples: [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58964/how-to-use-2-0-1-8-to-make-51), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/how-to-make-numbers-using-2018), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58998/create-equations-for-numbers-40-100-using-only-the-numbers-2018), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58743/make-numbers-93-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8), and [the one post that started them all](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8). There are even more but I assume this is enough to serve my point.

There's been a [similar discussion on chess puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/a-flood-of-chess-puzzles), but my opinion is that there, there are very clear differences - rooks are completely different from knights, etc. (Not gonna comment on whether that makes them more valid). For the 2018 puzzles, all that's different is:

- The numbers to make.
- The operators allowed.
- Whether or not the numbers should be in order

I was wondering what the community's standpoint on this was - are these similar enough to mark as duplicate, and be closed/deleted? Should they simply be downvoted, if not deemed interesting, in the hope that the authors will get the point?

Comment: Seems we had the same idea at almost the same time...

Comment: [Yet another 2018 puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/59111/11110)...

Comment: *Solution:* Write a program that solves every yearly puzzle for the next 100 years in advance, then automatically answer every yearly puzzle that comes up.

Comment: @Ambo100 Oh, devious. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: use one 8 and one each of the numbers 0-2 to make the number 2018...

Comment: There has been a few more of these questions recently, and it brought to light another issue with these kinda problems: Sometimes, even the posters themselves don't know if the puzzle has a solution, and relies on the ingenuity of the solvers to find one. Really makes these kinda puzzles feel cheap and low-effort to make...

Comment: @VotBear, yeah, that is definitely bad form. I had Random Numbers float through my head! I'll write them down and call it a puzzle!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of these puzzles aren't close-worthy as such: we have a [formation-of-numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation-of-numbers) tag with over 150 questions nearly all of the form "make `<number(s)>` using only `<number(s)>` and `<operations>`". Some of these are fun and challenging, while others are pretty prosaic, but on the whole I think the community does a pretty good job of sorting out the interesting from the uninteresting by their votes.

---

Historically, it's always been the case that a stream of very similar puzzles within a short timespan will have monotonically decreasing scores.

- Someone posts Puzzle #1 based on what's then a brilliant new idea, and it gets lots of upvotes.
- Someone else is inspired and posts Puzzle #2 based on the same idea, and it still gets a reasonable number of upvotes.
- Someone else gets in on the fun by posting Puzzle #3 based on the same idea, and it gets a lukewarm reception because the idea isn't novel any more.
- Someone else jumps on the bandwagon and posts Puzzle #4 based on the same idea, and people start to downvote.

Something roughly like this has happened time and time again on Puzzling SE. A 'craze' for some particular type of puzzle surges through the site, but quickly loses its momentum as people move on to some new idea. See also [A rise in low-quality questions (March 2015)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2826/5373) and its answers - the worries you raise have come up [time and time again](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5437/5373) here, and the site always survives. **This too shall pass.**

---

**So how do we tackle this surge of similar questions?** Vote, vote, vote! Your upvotes and downvotes are yours to use as you see fit, and the best way to discourage a rush of unimaginativity.

Let me just drop a reminder, though, that [a close-vote is not a super-downvote](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5479/5373). If one of these 2018 puzzles is completely covered by another, then we should close it as a *duplicate* ([case in point](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58998/5373)); but we shouldn't start closing individual questions in this class just because there are getting to be too many of them. If we want to declare all [formation-of-numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation-of-numbers) questions off-topic, then we can have a meta discussion about that and a mass close-voting spree; but, for example, [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58992/5373) (after the edits made to it) is no more off-topic than [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/50167/5373) and should be reopened.

In short:

> are these similar enough to mark as duplicate, and be closed/deleted? Should they simply be downvoted, if not deemed interesting, in the hope that the authors will get the point?

**Yes.** Some few of them are actually covered by others and can be marked as duplicates; the rest should simply be downvoted until they stop coming. Don't worry; we'll weather this inrush of puzzles as we've weathered so many others.

Comment: Another point I'd like to add is that questions saying "use any mathematical operation (except those in ⟨finite set⟩)" are almost always VTC-worthy as too broad.

Comment: @Ankoganit Yeah, I'd agree with closing the [original version](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/58992/1) of that puzzle. But I do think the edits salvage it somewhat, at least enough to make it on-topic (if not particularly interesting).

Comment: Sounds fair enough Rand. I haven't been around long enough to see those other waves, but I'll happily stick to your advises.

Comment: i like the last sentence. +1!